# Erro - to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, restful, spring-data

Já fui linha a linha pra saber o que tem de diferente entre um objeto que deu certo  e o que está dando errado e não consigo achar o problema. Este objeto Student está dando erro. Se eu comentar o get sobe normal.

Erro do codigo:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.school.repository.query.StudentRepositoryQuery.filtrar(com.school.repository.filter.StudentFilter,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property filtrar found for type Student!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.school.repository.query.StudentRepositoryQuery.filtrar(com.school.repository.filter.StudentFilter,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property filtrar found for type Student!
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filtrar found for type Student!
```

Classe Resource:

```
public class StudentResource {
    @GetMapping
    public Page<Student> getFiltreEntity(StudentFilter studentFilter, Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.filtrar(studentFilter, pageable);
    }
```

Classe Repository

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>, StudentRepositoryQuery{}
```

Classe Query

```
public interface StudentRepositoryQuery {
    Page<Student> filtrar(StudentFilter studentFilter, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Classe Impl

```
 public class StudentRepositoryImpl implements StudentRepositoryQuery{
        @Override
        public Page<Student> filtrar(StudentFilter studentFilter, Pageable pageable) {
                CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
                CriteriaQuery<Student> criteria = builder.createQuery(Student.class);
                Root<Student> root = criteria.from(Student.class);


                Predicate[] predicates = createFilter(studentFilter, builder, root);
                criteria.where(predicates);

                TypedQuery<Student> query = manager.createQuery(criteria);
                addPageRestrict(query, pageable);

            return new PageImpl<>(query.getResultList(), pageable, total(studentFilter));
        }
```

[Se precisar o projeto completo está aqui](https://github.com/CleristonLincoln/school-app/tree/master/src/main)

Comment: Tente renomear `StudentRepositoryImpl` para `StudentRepositoryQueryImpl`. Se funcionar, avise que eu crio uma resposta apropriada.

Comment: @StatelessDev O erro ainda continua. As outras que funcionam tambem estão sem o  query.

Answer (score 1):

Na classe StudentResource você deve adicionar uma variável/campo do tipo StudentRepository ou do que você precisar e anotar com @Autowired. Este seria o repository que está chamando dentro do método getFiltreEntity.

Na pude ver onde está a ligação entre StudentRepositoryQuery e StudentRepository.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, pra mim funcionou trocando a ordem da extensão na classe Repository

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>, StudentRepositoryQuery{}
```

ficaria assim:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>, StudentRepositoryQuery{}
```

Answer (score 0):

É uma questão de padrão de nomenclatura. Passei pelo mesmo problema a pouco e buscando na documentação do [spring-data/1.6.1.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html), na seção **1.3 Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories** percebi que a extensão do repositório precisa ter o mesmo nome de classe que o repositório, seguido do sufixo Impl, para que o spring encontre a implementação corretamente.

Exemplo:

---

```
//Interface for custom repository functionality: UserRepositoryCustom.java

interface UserRepositoryCustom {
     public void someCustomMethod(User user);
}
```

---

```
//Implementation of custom repository functionality: UserRepositoryImpl.java

class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {
  public void someCustomMethod(User user) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}
```

---

```
//Changes to the your basic repository interface: UserRepository.java

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {
  // Declare query methods here
}
```

Não sei se foi editado o post, mas do jeito que está, deveria funcionar corretamente.

Esta documentação de outra versão (3.0.1), seção [4.6.1. Customizing Individual Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) explica como implementar e também tem algumas notas sobre prioridades:

> Repositories may be composed of multiple custom implementations that are imported in the order of their declaration. Custom implementations have a higher priority than the base implementation and repository aspects. This ordering lets you override base repository and aspect methods and resolves ambiguity if two fragments contribute the same method signature. Repository fragments are not limited to use in a single repository interface. Multiple repositories may use a fragment interface, letting you reuse customizations across different repositories.